# How can I read the Command Line feedback from Python os.system()?

Tags: python

given the following Python command:

```
 os.system('snmpget -v 3 -u initial 172.17.171.113 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0')
 a=raw_input()    // in order to be able to see the result. I dont want the windows to close at the end.
```

How can I read th result of this command line command?

I tried     string=os.read(os.system,10)

but it isnt working... any ideas?
(I am using windows xp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well usually i'm using

```
import os


output = os.popen("snmpget -v 3 -u initial 172.17.171.113 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0").read()
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import subprocess
output, error = subprocess.Popen('snmpget -v 3 -u initial 172.17.171.113 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
```

OR

```
import subprocess
output = subprocess.check_output('snmpget -v 3 -u initial 172.17.171.113 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0'.split())
```

`output` contain command output.

Comment: Thanks!! Is there a way to get the string allready "parsed"? I mean something like sending the function two variable and get in each variable another value and not all the string to 'output' variable?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want get line by line?

Comment: If the result is a string like: "name: xxxx, value: yyyyy", then sending the function variable a and b will result in a=xxx and b=yyy

Comment: the outcome of this command is: "SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: xyz". is there a way to send the python function two variables a and b in order to get the 'sysName.0' in a, and 'xyz' in b?

Comment: a, b = "SNMPv2-MIB::sysName.0 = STRING: xyz".split(' = '); print a; print b

Answer (score 1):

With your eyes.

os.system only returns a number back to your process. You should use the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to read the stdout back into your process

eg

[subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
result = subprocess.check_output(['snmpget', '-v', '3', '-u', 'initial',
                                  '172.17.171.113', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0'])
```

Answer (score 1):

os.system doesn't return output of the command. It returns exit status of the command executed. Zero, on successful execution, non-zero on invalid commands.

If you want to read output, use commands module

```
import commands

output = commands.getoutput("snmpget -v 3 -u initial 172.17.171.113 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0")

====process output====
```

Or use subprocess modules mentioned by others!

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is the old way of doing it. The subprocess module is the preferred way now.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for letting me know. But it still works. Anyway updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't be better to do this natively?

- [PySNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/)
- [Python bindings for Net-SNMP](https://net-snmp.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/net-snmp/trunk/net-snmp/python/README) - this probably outperforms first